# API using mean stack application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have installed the new mean app and i want to add an api using that app. I have done some changes in server.js file i add the app.use and body parser to it to get data in json and included the route and the model and the mogodb database.

This is my server.js

```
'use strict';


   /*
   var cl = console.log;
   console.log = function(){
  console.trace();
  cl.apply(console,arguments);
   };
  */

  process.env.NODE_CONFIG_DIR = './config/env';

    // Requires meanio .
    var mean = require('meanio');
var cluster = require('cluster');
var deferred = require('q').defer();
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');



// Express
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Routes
app.use('/api', require('./web/api'));

// Code to run if we're in the master process or if we are not in debug mode/ running tests

if ((cluster.isMaster) &&
  (process.execArgv.indexOf('--debug') < 0) &&
  (process.env.NODE_ENV!=='test') && (process.env.NODE_ENV!=='development') &&
  (process.execArgv.indexOf('--singleProcess')<0)) {
//if (cluster.isMaster) {

    console.log('for real!');
    // Count the machine's CPUs
    var cpuCount = process.env.CPU_COUNT || require('os').cpus().length;

    // Create a worker for each CPU
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
        console.log ('forking ',i);
        cluster.fork();
    }

    // Listen for dying workers
    cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
        // Replace the dead worker, we're not sentimental
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.id + ' died :(');
        cluster.fork();

    });

// Code to run if we're in a worker process
} else {
    var workerId = 0;
    if (!cluster.isMaster)
    {
        workerId = cluster.worker.id;
    }

  // Dependencies

// Creates and serves mean application
    mean.serve({ workerid: workerId /* more options placeholder*/ }, function (app) {
      var config = app.getConfig();
      var port = config.https && config.https.port ? config.https.port : config.http.port;
      console.log('Mean app started on port ' + port + ' (' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ') cluster.worker.id:', workerId);

      deferred.resolve(app);
    });
}

module.exports = deferred.promise;
```

But when i run the localhost:3000/api/products it redirect me to the home page ie localhost:3000.

Thanks in advance.

api.js

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Models
var Product = require('./models/product');

// Routes
Product.methods(['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete']);
Product.register(router, '/products');

// Return router
module.exports = router;
```

model/product.js

```
// Dependencies
var restful = require('node-restful');
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

// Schema
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    sku: String,
    price: Number
});

// Return model
module.exports = restful.model('Products', productSchema);
```

Comment: please provide codes about `require('./web/api')`

Comment: both the api.js and models/product.js are added

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are connecting your Mongo database in your `server.js` file and that may be the cause of your issues. Try adding the following line after `var app = express;`:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/resources");
```

Note that `resources` would be the name of your MongoDB database.